# Compare Drawables on ImageViews

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a One-armed Bandit app. 
I have created an animation xml file to go through multiple images. When a button is clicked, the animation stops.

My question is how to compare the picture that one animation stopped on with that of another? So far I've tried something like this:

```
if(wheel1.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(wheel2.getBackground().getConstantState())) matches++;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you must be starting the animation with 
 `.animationStart()` 

just use  `.onAnimationStop()`  
 and it will trigger the event automatically.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I don't have any questions regarding how to stop or start the animations. I want to compare the pictures of the ImageViews when the animations stop to see if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

A `View` should not maintain application logic, the controller (your hosting `Activity` or `Fragment`) should.

That said, to achieve what you want use `View.setTag()` to apply a logical description of each `View` to it.
Then when stopping animation, loop through all `Views` you have and get their position on screen, get the `Views` mostly visible in each column of your bandit machine and compare their tags (`View.getTag()`)

for example, if the items animate vertically use below method to determine where the bandit stopped.

```
//the area where to compare views
int BOUND_TOP, BOUNT_DOWN;

//your content view
ViewGroup rootLayout;

//method to get information about what is visible
public List<Object> getVisibleViewTags() {
    List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();

    int count = rootLayout.getChildCount(); 
    for (int pos = 0; pos < count; pos++) {
        View child = rootLayout.getChildAt(pos);
        float translationY = child.getTranslationY();
        if (translationY > BOUND_TOP && translationY < BOUND_DOWN) {
            list.add(child.getTag());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Now you just need to attach information about a view as tag to it.
example:

```
view.setTag("view_apples");
```

or

```
view.setTag("view_bananas");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems like a terrible way to do it, but I guess it will have to do if there is no other way. Will this be able to put tags on all the pictures of the animation, even the ones that aren't currently visible?

Comment: as long as they exist, yes. it does not matter if they are currently visible

Comment: How do I know which is which? For example, how do I know which view in the list is the picture of an apple so I can put the appropriate tag on it?

Comment: when you inflate your layout from xml you can assign id's to views. if you inflate them programmatically you know what is what anyway

Comment: Can you assign ID's to the Drawables that are used in an ImageView though? Anyway, I found a solution using BitmapDrawable to compare my pictures.

Comment: as you can only have one drawable in an imageview at a time why not use the imageviews id? i do not understand what you want to achieve